# In Ask Different, visited questions are coloured the same as nonvisited

Tags: discussion, design, site-specific, ask-different

I think this is very unique of [Ask Different](//apple.stackexchange.com) compared to the vast majority, if not all, of the rest of the network.

I just visited "Equivalent of =SUM(ABOVE) in numbers?", and yet everything will look the same:

> [image: Ask Different]

How does that compare to the *[Law](//law.stackexchange.com)* Stack Exchange site where visited questions will be idiomatically coloured darker<sup>1</sup>?

> [image: The Law Stack Exchange site]

I have checked this happens to me in every laptop's browser. Is it a bug or feature?

<sub>**1**: And I can see this everywhere from the non-designed style to [Server Fault](//serverfault.com) to [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com) to [Software Recommendations](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) to [Android Enthusiasts](//android.stackexchange.com/) to [...], but not in [Super User](//superuser.com).</sub>

Or am I now just too old to see the difference between visited and nonvisited links in [Super User](//superuser.com) and [Ask Different](//apple.stackexchange.com)? I'm not a front-end specialist, but I believe I read link is `#008AD6` (`rgb(0, 138, 214)` as per classic [HTML color picker tool](//www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp)?) and visited would be `rgba(0,138,214,0.8)` (values are [Ask Different](//apple.stackexchange.com) particularly). Do you really find alpha difference enough for visited vs non visited link?

---

Looking again, I can see a slight, very subtle difference in visited vs non visited link at [Super User](//superuser.com). Inspecting the styles reveals a very different color, `#38A1CE` (`56, 161, 206`) for non visited vs `#50AEC6` (`80, 174, 198`) for visited, which when used in a large block it's clearly visible.

Comment: Oh it works on mobile Safari though. Not on Mac Safari or Firefox for that matter. That's why I was landing on the same questions again.. possible after title change. That bold in Ask wasn't required though..

Comment: This is like that on the other mobile SEs.